# I can't multiply two fields. Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I try to multiply price and quantity. but somethings went wrong.
'quantity' and 'price' both is IntegerField()

```
class BillListSum(generics.GenericAPIView):

    def get(self, request):
        bill = Bill.objects.all()
        serializer = BillSerializer(bill)
        all_sum = Bill.objects.all().aggregate(Sum(int('cart__drink__price')*'cart__quantity' ))['cart__drink__price__sum']
        return Response({'sum': all_sum if all_sum else 0 , 'objects': serializer.data})
```

Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'cart__drink__price'
Please help me! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly what you need.

```
from django.db import connection
from django.db.models import Sum, F

class BillListSum(generics.GenericAPIView):

    def get(self, request):
        bill = Bill.objects.all()
        serializer = BillSerializer(bill)
        all_sum = Bill.objects.all().aggregate(val=Sum(F('cart__drink__price')*F('cart__quantity')))['val']
        print(all_sum) # returns int

        print(connection.queries) # This will return queries performed in your views. make monitoring using this.

        return Response({'sum': all_sum if all_sum else 0 , 'objects': serializer.data})
```

If you want to use SQL `GROUP BY` you should use `annotate()` `Manager/QuerySet` method. also check [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/) about aggregations. Everything is in details.

Comment: so if i want group by it. How can i do it. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try like this:

```
from django.db.models import F, IntegerField

class BillListSum(generics.GenericAPIView):
    def get(self, request):
        ...
        all_sum = Bill.objects.all().aggregate(sum_price = Sum(F('cart__drink__price')*F('cart__quantity'), output_field=IntegerField()))['sum_price']
```

### Updated answer with Group By

```
from django.db.models import F, IntegerField, ExpressionWrapper

class BillListSum(generics.GenericAPIView):
    def get(self, request):
        bill = Bill.objects.all().annotate(total_price = ExpressionWrapper(F('cart__drink__price')*F('cart__quantity'), output_field=IntegerField())).order_by('total_price')
        serializer = BillSerializer(bill)
        all_sum = bill.aggregate(sum_price=Sum(F('total_price'))).get('sum_price')
        # rest of the code
```

Comment: could i ask you one more question, please?

Comment: Sure, if its relevant to the question.

Comment: thank you, I want to group by it. I use values(), but it's not work fine.
all_sum = Bill.objects.all().values('cart__drink__branch').aggregate(sum_price = Sum(F('cart__drink__price')*F('cart__quantity'), output_field=IntegerField()))['sum_price']

Comment: @BáPhúcNguyễn please try the updated answer section